# Hive: check what parameters are set in a session or for a job?

Tags: hive

we have few parameters in Hive such as the following:

```
set hive.cbo.enable=true;
set hive.compute.query.using.stats=true;
set hive.stats.fetch.column.stats=true;
set hive.stats.fetch.partition.stats=true;
set mapreduce.job.running.map.limit=50;
```

how do I check which parameters are set(true)??
how many mappers a particular job is using can be seen in GUI, but how can I check the status of other parameters? is there a way to do so??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just print `set param_name;`

```
hive> set hive.cbo.enable;
hive.cbo.enable=true
```

Or in a query:

```
hive> select ${hiveconf:hive.cbo.enable};
OK
true
Time taken: 1.042 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

More complex example (check boolean variable in a case):

```
hive> select case when ${hiveconf:hive.cbo.enable} then 1 else 0 end;
OK
1
Time taken: 0.041 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
hive>
```

In a shell:

```
hive_cbo_enable=$(hive -e 'select ${hiveconf:hive.cbo.enable} ;')
echo "$hive_cbo_enable"
```

true

All params which is true:

```
hive -e 'set;' | grep "=true"

datanucleus.fixedDatastore=true
datanucleus.rdbms.useLegacyNativeValueStrategy=true
dfs.block.access.token.enable=true
dfs.client.block.write.replace-datanode-on-failure.enable=true
dfs.client.mmap.enabled=true
dfs.datanode.drop.cache.behind.reads=true
dfs.datanode.drop.cache.behind.writes=true
...
```

Comment: Thanks a ton.. this is what I wanted :)